# Why can't the compiler select the correct String.contains method when using this lambda shorthand?

Tags: scala, overloading, type-inference, implicit-conversion, implicit

Say I want to check if a string contains **any** of the letters in "cory":

```
def hasCory(input: String): Boolean = {
  val myName = "cory"
  input.exists(myName.contains)
}
```

The compiler complains with:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : CharSequence => Boolean
required: Char => Boolean
```

Scala provides the `Char`-accepting method I want [in StringOps](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#contains%5BA1%3E:A%5D(elem:A1):Boolean):

[image: scaladoc showing the contains method signature]

But it appears that the compiler cannot see this method unless I change the code to one of:

```
input.exists(myName.contains(_))
input.exists(c => myName.contains(c))
```

Instead in the original example it appears to be using [Java String's `contains` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)), which indeed *does* accept a `CharSequence`:

[image: documentation of Java String.contains method]

Is this working as intended? Why can't the compiler see that I want the `Char` version of `contains`?

Comment: `String` is a collection of `Char`, not of sub-`String`, `exists` is defined accordingly (type mismatch).

Comment: The signature of `exists` is `def exists(p: (Char) => Boolean): Boolean`, so you need to pass it a method that takes a `Char` and returns a `Boolean`. That is exactly the signature of the Scala StringOps `contains` method.

Comment: I think what you mean is `def hasCory(input: String): Boolean = input.contains("cory")`

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik no, that would check if the name "cory" is in the string `input`. I want to check if the string `input` contains any of the letters in my name, ie any of the characters `c`, `o`, `r`, or `y`. Either way, this question is not so much about how to do that specific check as it is about _why_ the compiler won't let me do it unless I explicitly declare the intermediate `c` value.

Comment: @CoryKlein you can write `input.exists(myName.contains(_))` too.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I'll add that to the question as well, especially because it does seem to narrow down what the potential list of answers would be.

Comment: IME automatic eta expansion sometimes fails for cases where: there is overloading, overloading is done by extension method. I guess, to eta expand compiler has to be certain of the type of a method, to use extension method it must be obvious from the types that extension method is the expected method, and when you put it together compiler has no reason to think that there is some extension method it can use instead of a normal method, and make it eta expand without writing `(_)`. Many Cats extension methods have similar issue - unless you spoon feed it with types, compiler won't find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringOps` is [an implicit conversion](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L401)

```
@inline implicit def augmentString(x: String): StringOps = new StringOps(x)
```

And implicit conversion are applicable [in three cases](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#views) only:

> 1. If an expression  is of type , and  does not conform to the expression's expected type pt.
> 2. In a selection .
>    with  of type , **if the selector  does not denote an accessible member of** .
> 3. In a selection .(args)
>    with  of type , if the selector  denotes some member(s) of , but none of these members is applicable to the arguments args.

When you write `myName.contains` it's none of the three cases (in particular,
not the 2nd case because `contains` **is** an accessible member of `String`) so `StringOps` can't be applied and it's `String#contains(CharSequence)` and type mismatch error.

When you write `myName.contains(_)` or `c => myName.contains(c)` it's the 3rd case so `StringOps` can be applied and it's `StringOps#contains(Char)` after implicit conversion.

So yes, it's working as intended.

Comment: I suspected as much. I think I was initially most suprised by this because I didn't realize that `String` _is_ `java.util.String`. I've been operating under the assumption that Scala had it's own `String` that was _compatible_ with Java's. Anyway - thank you for the well cited and thorough answer! I learned much.

Comment: @CoryKlein Well, in Scala `String` is `scala.Predef.String`, which is an alias for `java.util.String`.

Comment: Exactly. It’s like a Desktop Shortcut to Java String.