# Scala implicit implicit

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, implicit

I'm trying to do some implicit magic in my code but the issue is very simple and I have extracted it out here.  It seems a bit strange since from what I've read the following should work.

```
   implicit class Foo(value: Double) {
      def twice = 2*value
    }

    2.0.twice

    implicit def strToDouble(x: String) = Try(x.toDouble) match {
      case Success(d) => d
      case Failure(_) => 0.0
    }

    strToDouble("2.0").twice
    val a: Double = "2.0"
    val b: Double = "equals 0.0"
    "2.0".twice
```

I get a compile error

```
 value twice is not a member of String
[error]     "2.0".twice
```

I get you compiler, twice is defined for `Double`s, not `String`s. But I did tell you how to go from `String`s to `Double`s, and there is no ambiguity here (as far as I can tell), so shouldn't you be able to note that `"2.0".twice` can be done by doing `strToDouble("2.0").twice`?

Am I missing something here? Or is this an optimisation so that the compiler doesn't try out all the possible permutations of `implicits` (which would grow super-exponentially, I think as a factorial). I suppose I'm looking for a confirmation or rejection of this really.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, **implicit conversions** are bad; prefer _extension methods_. - Second, **implicit conversions** without explicit return types are even more dangerous. - Third, that **implicit class** should also be a **value class** so there is no overhead on the _extension method_ `implicit class Foo(private val value: Double) extends AnyVal`. - Last but not least, the compiler will never apply more than one implicit conversion. Otherwise, it would be very slow and complex; rather write an additional _extension method_ `twice` on String.

Comment: I belive you will find most of your answers here:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html

Comment: I would call this a safeguard, rather than an optimization. Considering that everything can be converted into a string this would also mean that any extension method defined on a string can work on top of anything. I would also say that potentially endless implicit conversion could very easily freeze the compiler while giving little hints on what's going on.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez
First: Yeah, I agree. The library I'm trying to do this with however requires such implicits for `Seq[T]` and I would have to create an implicit for each implementation for `Seq[Seq[T]]`, `Seq[Seq[Seq[...]]` etc, so I was hoping to define one single `flatMap` implicit which would reduce the `Seq[Seq[T]]` to `Seq[T]` and this would then generalise to all depths.
Second: I didn't declare the return type here because it wasn't central to the issue but I take your point.
Last: This seems to be the confirmation of my point that this is an optimisation

Comment: @niurepu why a library would require you to add an implicit conversion? Also, I believe it makes sense to think differently from flatting a `Seq[Seq[T]]` than a `Seq[Seq[Seq[T]]` the more nested **Seqs** the more complex the operation is, trying to hide that will hide a lot of complexity and easily allow people to design very bad abstractions _(in any case **Seqs** are bad, use concrete collections instead)_. - Finally, this is not really an optimization, is a design decision that determines the semantics of the language...

Comment: ... Multiple implicit conversion would not only make the compiler slower, will make code difficult to reason about, and would allow the design of very bad abstractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want extension method to be applicable even after implicit conversion, you can fix the definition of implicit class

```
implicit class Foo[A](value: A)(implicit ev: A => Double) {
  def twice: Double = 2 * value
}

implicit def strToDouble(x: String): Double = ???

2.0.twice   //compiles
"2.0".twice //compiles
```

> I get you compiler, `twice` is defined for `Double`s, not `String`s. But I
> did tell you how to go from `String`s to `Double`s, and there is no
> ambiguity here (as far as I can tell), so shouldn't you be able to
> note that `"2.0".twice` can be done by doing `strToDouble("2.0").twice`?

According to specification implicit conversions are applicable in three cases only

[Why can't the compiler select the correct String.contains method when using this lambda shorthand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291510/why-cant-the-compiler-select-the-correct-string-contains-method-when-using-this/)

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#views

The conversion of `2.0.twice` to `Foo(2.0).twice` is the 2nd case and the conversion of `"2.0"` to `strToDouble("2.0")` is the 1st case. As you can see there is no item that they can be applied together. So if you want them to be applicable together you should specify that explicitly like I showed above.

Similarly if you defined conversions from `A` to `B` and from `B` to `C` this doesn't mean you have a conversion from `A` to `C`

```
case class A(i: Int)
case class B(i: Int)
case class C(i: Int)
implicit def aToB(a: A): B = B(a.i)
implicit def bToC(b: B): C = C(b.i)

A(1): B    // compiles
B(1): C    // compiles
// A(1): C //doesn't compile
```